# TeX Live error on Ubuntu 10.04: pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool

Tags: texlive, errors, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 over-top of Ubuntu 9.04, preserving my /home partition, but aside from that partition, it was a fresh install. I installed the texlive package (2009-7) from Ubuntu's main repository.

Now, when I try to run latex or pdflatex on a `.tex` file, I get the not so helpful error:

```
brian@thoralf:~/tmp$ pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /home/brian/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[I asked, then search the net. I've made my answer community wiki so as not to look like I'm rep-hunting.]

There was a [bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-bin/+bug/543529) against ubuntu 10.04 beta. I'm somewhat surprised it's not been fixed as it makes latex rather useless.

One commentator on the bug thread said that deleting `/home/.texmf-var` worked for them. Worked for me, too.

Comment: I guess this tells you the balance of users who use LaTeX doing 'over the top' installations against those who do fresh ones!

Comment: depending on your distribution, you may need to `rm -rf ~/.texlive/texmf-var`

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the other answers, the problem is caused by some local files not being updated upon an texlive upgrade. In my case `fmtutil --all` fixed the problem. (Neither sudo nor the `fmtutil-sys` version, those files seem to be upgraded by the package, just the stuff in the user dir isnt.)

Answer (score 7):

I was having the exact same problem when I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and then to 12.10 (even thought I'm a year behind). I could not compile latex, similar to the first post. This is what I was getting:

```
$ latex file_name.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /home/myUname/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I used the solution stated above. Instead of deleting, I just renamed it. ie.

```
$ mv .texmf-var/ .texmf-var-BackUp
```

In my case, the .texmf-var folder was in the /home/myUname folder and not in /home folder. Now it compiles like it used to. Just wanted to add this in case others were looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, and saw this fix on a few community pages. I was hesitant to delete that directory, so I simply moved it. It totally worked, and now I can compile again. Thank you! I was afraid I'd lose billable hours over this, but it was an easy fix!

Comment: `~/.texmf-var` contains only automatically generated content, so it is always safe to delete it.

Comment: @mpg: That is not true for me; I've got a manual font entry in `pdftex.map`. (Maybe I should have done that differently??)

Comment: HUm... good point. How did you add this line? `updmap --enable Map=name.map` or manual editing of the file? With `updmap`, information _should_ (not 100% sure) be kept in `TEXMFCONFIG` (probably `~/.texmf-config` for you). However, you need to rerun `updmap` after deleting `TEXMFVAR`, indeed.