# no compilation possible after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: errors, kile

since upgrading ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04 the compilation of .tex-files in Kile does not work anymore.
Everytime when I try to do 'PDFLatex' I get the following error:

`[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1
Cannot open log file; did you run LaTeX?`

The output is:

```
*****  
*****     PDFLaTeX output:   
*****     cd "/home/myName"  
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode BA.tex  
*****  
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)  
restricted \write18 enabled.  
---! /home/myName/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool  
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied) `
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Kile, but that didn't help. I get the error for every document, so the problem is not caused by 'BA.tex'.
I don't really know what causes the error. Does anyone of you has a suggestion?

Comment: > myName/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool

I'm not familiar with ubuntu, but the message
says that you have to regenerate your personal
format files. Can you try

`fmtutil --all`

?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate question of [TeX Live error on Ubuntu 10.04: pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/tex-live-error-on-ubuntu-10-04-pdflatex-fmt-doesnt-match-pdftex-pool).

You should try deleting the folder. It's only a var directory, it shoud do no harm.

Comment: Thank you for the link, removing .texmv-var solved my problem.